# Where is the Cartopy 's repository in Windows installed through Anaconda?

Tags: matplotlib, cartopy

I would like to check what files are already in the repository of Cartopy in order to find their names and use them as part of code.

I looked for "Cartopy" in Anaconda3 directory, also look for "*.zip" files

The line where I want to use this information is the following:
ax1.add_feature(cartopy.feature.NaturalEarthFeature('cultural', '**admin_0_boundary_lines_land**', '10m'),
               edgecolor='black',
               facecolor='none')

I would like to know names of the features available and location on disk to add more.

Comment: There are no files in the repo. The natural earth features are downloaded from `http://naciscdn.org/naturalearth/{resolution}/{category}/ne_{resolution}_{name}.zip`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  How can I know what is available, names of the features to be used in the syntax of the code??

Comment: You can check https://www.naturalearthdata.com